# WCF, WS-Addressing and autogenerated service for receiving answers

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, soap, ws-addressing

I'm going to consume a 3-rd party Web Service which uses WS-Addressing for sending asynchronous replies to the requests.The schemas are rather complicated and creating a service from scratch for receiving answers can take a lot of time.

So I am wondering if is there any way to autogenerate a WCF service for receiving replies along with a proxy client for that service?